# Do I need both jquery.js and jquery-migrate.min.js?

Tags: jquery

I am managing [this](https://glamourina.net/) blog.
As you can see, it loads both `jquery.js?ver=1.12.4` and `jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1`

Do I need both of them, or I can safely remove one of them? Isn't the `jquery-migrate.min.js` the newest version of jquery.js?

How do I know if I can remove one of them or not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As stated in the official blog of **jQuery**. Note that **WordPress** is mentioned in the quote.

> ## jQuery Migrate 1.4.1 released, and the path to jQuery 3.0
>
> Version 1.4.1 of the jQuery Migrate plugin has been released. It has only a few changes but the most important of them fixes a problem with unquoted selectors that seems to be very common in some **WordPress** themes. In most cases Migrate can automatically fix this problem when it is used with jQuery 1.12.x or 2.2.x, although it may not be able to repair some complex selectors. The good news is that all the cases of unquoted selectors reported in **WordPress** themes appear to be fixable by this version of Migrate!

A quick answer to your question; **yes** you can remove the *jQuery migration* script and if you don't see any unwanted behavior after the removal of the script, then it's safe to say that you can completely remove the reference migration script.

Can be read in [here](https://blog.jquery.com/2016/05/19/jquery-migrate-1-4-1-released-and-the-path-to-jquery-3-0/)

Comment: And is it normal than the blog is using jquery.js?ver=1.12.4 ?
Shouldn't it use the newest 3.x? Only then I can safely remove jQuery Migrate?

Comment: **jQuery** version `1.12.4` ships with WordPress core by default. You can use the latest version of the script which is version `3`, just make sure to call the `deregister_script('jquery')` and that includes the removal of the migration script, then again enqueue the latest version of the script to use.

Comment: Thank you. Removed migrate and taken jquery 3 from google. And it seems to be working fine

Answer (score 4):

**Yes you can remove JQuery Migrate** to speed up the loading of your page on the client side.

### What is jQuery Migrate?

The jQuery Migrate module (**jquery-migrate.min.js**) is a javascript library that allows you to preserve the compatibility of your jQuery code developed for versions of jQuery older than 1.9. JQuery Migrate also allows developers to detect deprecated code that is no longer supported by the latest jQuery libraries and to adapt it according to the newest versions of jQuery 1.9 and higher.

### PHP code to disable jQuery Migrate in WordPress

This is the code I'm using for my clients and it is the right way to remove it properly on the client side without affecting any other components in the WordPress Dashboard. Grab this code and paste it in your functions.php file to remove the JQuery:

```
/**
 * Disable jQuery Migrate in WordPress.
 *
 * @author Guy Dumais.
 * @link https://en.guydumais.digital/disable-jquery-migrate-in-wordpress/
 */
add_filter( 'wp_default_scripts', $af = static function( &$scripts) {
    if(!is_admin()) {
        $scripts->remove( 'jquery');
        $scripts->add( 'jquery', false, array( 'jquery-core' ), '1.12.4' );
    }    
}, PHP_INT_MAX );
unset( $af );
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Or you could just enque `jquery-core` which does not include `jquery-migrate`: wp_enqueue_script('jquery-core');